# Setting event listener in a thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, audiotrack

I start a new thread to play audio. At the beginning of the run method ,I create an `audiotrack` at first.Then I set `audioTrack.setPlaybackPositionUpdateListener` to do some stuff when the `audiotrack` finished playing the audio. In the end, I call `audiotrack.write()` to actually play audio.

Code snippet is down below:

```
@Override
public void run() {
audioTrack = new  AudioTrack(listenerService.m_amAudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL, listenerService.sampleRate, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO, listenerService.audioFormat, listenerService.minBufSize / 8, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
audioTrack.setPlaybackPositionUpdateListener(new  AudioTrack.OnPlaybackPositionUpdateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onMarkerReached(AudioTrack track) {
        endReached();
    }
});
audioTrack.play();
audioTrack.setNotificationMarkerPosition(959);
audioTrack.write(rReadShortBuffer, 0, rReadShortBuffer.length);
audioTrack.flush();
}

public void endReached(){
....

}
```

My problem is that I expect the `reachEnd()` method will get executed in the same thread in which the `audiotrack` is created. Because the event listener is belong to the `audiotrack`,and the `audiotrack` is spawned and set that event in this thread.So all the stuff should be contained in this thread. This makes sense to me.But the program is not running this way as supposed. The thread that creates `audiotrack` seems get terminated after executed all the code inside the `run()` method and then the `reachEnd` method is executed in the `main` thread.

Do you guys know the reason of this behavior and how to make the `endReached` fired in the same thread as the one created the `audiotrack`? Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: The playback did reach the marker because I could debug into the listener event(endReached). But Then I found the current thread was in the main ui thread. Maybe it is because the thread that creates the audiotrack has terminated after all the code gets executed in the run method and there is no loop or sleep to keep it blocked.

Comment: @pskink, do you think the thread that created audiotrack will get terminated immediately once it runs to the end of run method. So when the playback event fires, the system will put the event to the main ui thread to process since it can not find the original thread that created audiotrack.

Comment: @pskink, It seems that there is something wrong with my network. I can not get access to pastebin.com. Right now I am managing to use handler and looper. I will tell you about the result once I get it done.

Comment: Thank you so much . Let me give it a try.

Comment: @pskink, It failed. The playback event still got fired in the main ui thread. I am going to try yosriz's method. I will tell you about it when I get it done.

Comment: it cannot get fired in the background thread, did you see `while` loop? you have to feed `AudioTrack` with data in that loop, otherwise you will get buffer underflow soon...

Comment: Thanks for the reminding.I see the while loop now. It's a very brilliant trick to sync the write of audiotrack and the thread that created audiotrack. However, during the step by step debug, the playback event indeed happens in the main ui thread:(

Comment: why do you need it in other thread? whats wrong with UI thread?

Comment: I need the program to play multiple sounds at once.(Listen to multiple users speaking). The audio resource is from inputstream of a tcp socket. I distract bytes segment from the inputstream and check the header part to identify this segment belong to which user. Then feed the audio bytes to the corresponding thread to play.

Comment: so instead of `FileInputStream` as in my example just use `PipedInputStream`

Comment: PipedInputStream looks a good option for this kind of task,but it is also a little bit complicated.Currently the normal inputstream is enough for my need.

Comment: all you need is PipedOutputStream in the network thread and PipedInputStream in the AudioTrack thread, thats all

Comment: Thanks.It looks cool.I will do some study on this approach.

Comment: @pskink, Handler and looper works. Give the playback listener a handler parameter could make the playback event fired in that handler which is in the same thread created the audiotrack. But becuase the audiotrack.write will keep the thread busy until it has written all the bytes, so track.setNotificationMarkerPosition() does nothing until the end of track.write.

Comment: Since I found audiotrack.write will block the current thread,so actually I do not need this playback listener.I can just wait the audiotrack to write off all the bytes. Then choose to play next block of bytes or use looper to kind of make this thread sleep, and let other thread communicate to it with a handler in it. Hopefully I make it clear. I have not fully examine this idea yet.

Comment: this is what i said from the very beginning: you dont need that listener at all, just feed `AudioTrack` with new data, also there is no need for a `HandlerThread` or `Looper` stuff

Comment: I had a wrong impression that the audiotrack.write is a non-block method and I never test it:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's happen because your thread doesn't have Looper, (like [HandlerThread](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/HandlerThread.html)).
Although the docs doesn't state this, if your thread that creates the `AudioTrack` doesn't have `Looper`, `AudioTrack` will use main looper, which means event will be scheduled on a `Handler` of main thread, and will be fired on the main thread.

Comment: I find the doc says that in my case, the event will be fired in the same thread that created the audiotrack. Is it possible that this issue is caused by that the thread has terminated when the playback event gets fired.So the system give the event to the main ui thread to process.Could you explain me more details about how to setup a looper for this thread? I think that makes pretty sense but I am a little bit confused how to implement this idea.

Comment: it is correct that it will set it to the thread that created the audiotrack, but what's not stated that it depends on whether the thread has Looper (you can see a clue on the second overload that requires Handler, that AudioTrack needs Handler to fire the event, and simple thread just don't have Handler.

Comment: regarding how to do this, please read about handler/looper, you can use HandlerThread as suggested above, to create thread with a looper.
Basically Looper/Handler it's mean that the thread has message queue, and each action on this thread happens sequentially in order arrived to the queue, this is how main/UI thread operating, you need a background thread that works in this way.

Comment: Thank you. Handler and looper works very well in this situation. They add so much power  to a normal thread.